# Get specific Count for Character from a column without using a function or Stored Proc

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a column on a table [SampleTable] called [MyColumn] and i would like the number of time this character appears on the column. The character is ;

Excel has a simple solution for this
=LEN()-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(,";",""))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT LEN(MyColumn) - LEN(REPLACE(MyColumn, ';', ''))
FROM SampleTable
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

For best readability in code this is best done with a UDF. For example, the one from [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/count-character.aspx):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_CountChar] ( @pInput VARCHAR(1000), @pSearchChar CHAR(1) )
RETURNS INT
BEGIN

DECLARE @vInputLength        INT
DECLARE @vIndex              INT
DECLARE @vCount              INT

SET @vCount = 0
SET @vIndex = 1
SET @vInputLength = LEN(@pInput)

WHILE @vIndex <= @vInputLength
BEGIN
    IF SUBSTRING(@pInput, @vIndex, 1) = @pSearchChar
        SET @vCount = @vCount + 1

    SET @vIndex = @vIndex + 1
END

RETURN @vCount

END
GO
```